# How to check current category has tags in liquid shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How to check if a current category has tags in liquid Shopify?

Suppose I am on a category page, I want to check if the category has tags or not.

Comment: Hi Gufran. Can you describe what you've tried so far (with examples of code if relevant), and how that hasn't worked? Be as specific as possible, so people can understand your problem enough to help.

Comment: Thanks Stan,

I have done what I was looking for.

Actually the main problem was that I wanted to display sub-categories when click on category instead of products. after that if someone click on sub-categories then all projects will for this sub-categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{% if collection.all_tags.size > 0 %}
  collection has tags
{% else %}
  collection has no tags
{% endif %}
```